# How to trigger the listen button on the Google-translate page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, google-translate, userscripts

I want to add shortcuts to the Google-translate page.
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to clear the `textarea`; press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to pronounce.

This is the current user script: [userscripts.org/scripts/review/110928](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/110928)

I do not know how to trigger the listen button on that page.

I tried:

```
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var cb = document.getElementById("gt-src-listen"); 
  cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

but it does not work. (`gt-src-listen` is id of the listen button.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google uses some pretty screwy code, several events seem to be required to get that button to play.

This works in Chrome:

```
function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); 
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true); 
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

var srcListenButton  = document.getElementById('gt-src-listen');

triggerMouseEvent (srcListenButton, 'mouseover');
triggerMouseEvent (srcListenButton, 'mousedown');
triggerMouseEvent (srcListenButton, 'mouseup');
```

(For now; Google continually breaks things).

Nothing works in Firefox, and those buttons have never played for me, even manually clicking, in that browser.

Comment: thank you for your answer. this is the final user script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/110928