# How can I click an item by condition with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey, userscripts

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_id" id="my_id" value="1">

<ul class="myList clearfix" id="thismyList">
<li class="myBullet" id="answer1">blabla1</li>
<li class="myBullet" id="answer2">blabla2</li>
<li class="myBullet" id="answer3">blabla3</li>
```

In this page I want to something like this:

```
if document.getElementById('my_id').value=="1"
document.getElementById('answer1').click;
if document.getElementById('my_id').value=="2"
document.getElementById('answer3').click;
if document.getElementById('my_id').value=="3"
document.getElementById('answer1').click;
if document.getElementById('my_id').value=="4"
document.getElementById('answer2').click;
```

I write this to show what I want. I know that code is wrong. But I think that explains what I want. How can I do that?

Comment: And you forgot parantheses to *call* the *click* function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for that would be:

```
switch (document.getElementById('my_id').value) {
    case "1":
        document.getElementById ('answer1').click ();
        break;
    case "2":
        document.getElementById ('answer3').click ();
        break;
    case "3":
        document.getElementById ('answer1').click ();
        break;
    case "4":
        document.getElementById ('answer2').click ();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

---

Note that in some cases, you may need to trigger mouse events like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137323/331508).

Comment: this doesn't work with click by id but I combined this code with code in this question's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971661/how-can-i-click-a-li-item-with-greasemonkey and it works. thanks.

Comment: It's good that you got it working, but there is no way for anyone to know that you wanted to click based on text values, versus ID's, based on the question you posed here.  We answer the question asked, NOT the question as filtered by previous questions unless you specifically reference them (which wasn't done).

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to invoke the click behaviour of a function you should just call.

```
document.getElementById('id').click();
```

I think it should works like you did without the '()' also.